# WPF SerializationException: Main Window is not marked as Serializable?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, observablecollection, binaryformatter

In my `MainWindow`, I have an `ObservableCollection<Video>` called *videos* which holds *Video* objects. The class *Video* is marked as `[Serializable]` (I also tried it as `[Serializable()]`). I want to `Serialize` and `Deserialize` the whole collection with a `BinaryFormatter` the following way:

Serialization:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream("Saves.bin",
               FileMode.Create,
               FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
        formatter.Serialize(stream, videos);
}
```

Deserialization:

```
 BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream("Saves.bin",
              FileMode.Open,
              FileAccess.Read,
              FileShare.Read))
 {
        videos = (ObservableCollection<Video>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
 }
```

This [DotNetPerls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/serialize-list) article demostrating the `Serialization` of `List`s operates similarly to my method, while a comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225853/why-my-observablecollection-serialization-doesnt-work) SO article suggests that the previous problem with the `Serialization` of `ObservableCollection`s does not persist in later versions of .Net (I'm using VS 2017 with the latest .Net). I do not store `Window` objects in my project.

The error complains about the `MainWindow` not marked as `Serializable` when I populate my UI elements with the underlying data loaded into the fields using `DataBinding`, when I load the data *only*, the error refers to `Window` not marked as `Serializable`, instead of *the* `MainWindow`.
I had problems with `Events`, but I marked them with the `[field: NonSerialized()]` attribute, so this is not the problem (at least I would not think so).
So what am I doing wrong? Why does the formatter want to serialize `MainWindow` in the first place? Should I use `XMLSerialization` instead of `BinaryFormatter`?

**EDIT:** I tried the exact same syntax as shown in the Perls article, but it gave the same results.

Comment: Does your Video class keep a reference to the Window?

Comment: No, whenever I use one of my `window` objects in a method, I keep reinitializing them like in NumberSelector num = new NumberSelector(); inside the method.

Comment: Interestingly, XMLserialization works after some tweaking and modifications to the code: the XMLSerializer throw an error, for example, that my code has _circular reference_ to objects.  This _was_ actually the case, because I wanted to keep a reference of the parent in every child element, but I replaced it now with an event-based implementation and it works fine. Could this be the reason behind the previous error?

Comment: Please show us your `Video` class and how exactly you populate your data.