# XML file -> Datatabel -> ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, listview, observablecollection

I got the otherway around `ObservableCollection -> datatabel -> XML File`.

Can also load the `XML file -> Datatabel -> ListView`.

But the `ListView` is also used in another Page of the application, so I need it bound to `ObservableCollection` again.

I hadn't luck finding similar problem, which solution worked for me. ([DataTable to observable collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759603/wpf-datatable-to-observable-collection)).

---

Okay, so I've been looking into `XML Serialize` and `XML Deserialize`. (Followed this how to: [What is the easiest way to save an Observable collectin of object to an XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194931/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-save-an-observable-collectin-of-object-to-an-xml-file))

It saves into a file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSong xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

When I try to load it, Listview doesn't refresh. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: If you need any code, just say which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What is the easiest way to save an Observable collectin of object to an XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194931/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-save-an-observable-collectin-of-object-to-an-xml-file)

Making my whole Collection public, and the XML Serialized etc. Solved it.